# how to get rid of karna pisachi if you effected by it through black magic

Tags: human

According to Hindu mythology there is an entity call Karna Pisachi (Pisachini), if you were under influence of pisachas through black magic, how to get rid of it according to Hindu Exorcism.

Comment: there is a specific method to do sadhana of karna pisachni according to tantra. if you succeeded it will keep telling you about the past present and future of people. so it is a tantric kind of fortune-telling. you cannot get under influence by it.

Comment: Consult someone who is adept in tantric practices. Many now a days are offering service through youtube, it's hard to get rid of it as she has stronger force. Only and Adept or a guru with long and strong satvik sadhna with yogic experties can help you.